# Default image being displayed even after uploading another picture in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm working on a website where users can post advertisements on houses they want to put up on rent.
So I have an image field in models.py, but no matter which picture I upload, the system keeps displaying the default photo. I have set up the media root and url as per the documentation in my settings.py and also added it to my urls.

models.py:

```
class advertisements(models.Model):
place=models.CharField(max_length=30)
address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
bedroom=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
rent=models.PositiveIntegerField()
size=models.PositiveIntegerField()
date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
owner= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='defaulthouse.jpg',upload_to='house_pics')


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('advertisement_details', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    image=Image.open(self.image.path)
```

views.py:

```
class AdvertisementCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model= advertisements
fields=['image', 'place','address','bedroom','bathroom','rent','size']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.owner=self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

path('', AdvertisementListView.as_view(), name='HomePage'),
path('advertisements/<int:pk>/',AdvertisementDetailsView.as_view() , name='advertisement_details'),
path('create_advertisements',AdvertisementCreateView.as_view(), name='create_advertisements'),
path('your_advertisements',views.your_advertisements, name='your_advertisements'),
path('advertisements/<int:pk>/update',AdvertisementUpdateView.as_view() , name='advertisement_update'),
path('advertisements/<int:pk>/delete',AdvertisementDeleteView.as_view() , name='advertisement_delete'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
     <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 text-center"><h3>House Information</h3></legend> 
     <h5 class="card-title">Location: {{object.place}} </h5> 
     <img src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">    
     <p> Full Address: {{object.address}}</p>  
     <p>Number of bedrooms: {{object.bedroom}}</p>
     <p>Number of Bathrooms: {{object.bathroom}}</p>
     <p>House/Apartment Size: {{object.size}} squarefeet</p>
     <p>Rent per month: {{object.rent}} taka</p>
     <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 text-center"><h3>Owner Information</h3></legend>
     <p>Owner Name: {{object.owner}}</p>
     <p>Advertisement Posted on: {{object.date_posted}}</p>
     {% if object.owner == user %}
    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'advertisement_update' object.id%}">Update</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'advertisement_delete' object.id%}">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Is the url to the image different between objects? Are the other fields different?

Comment: @schillingt the url to the image is different between objects

Comment: Are you submitting your form with the correct enctype, `multipart/form-data`?